# RewriteRule in .htaccess is not working how I expected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the code I use:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*) page.php?name=$1&pagination=$2
```

But if `$_GET['pagination']` is not set or the url is not set as `page/name/` I get error **object not found**.

I want default link  to be just `page/name` not `page/name/` and pagination to show as `page/name/[page number]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so.

```
RewriteRule ^page(/?)$ page.php [L]
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z]+)/(.*)(/?)$ page.php?name=$1&pagination=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The problem still persists